# php.ini stops my ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a page with some jquery ajax calls, following are the first two. This page worked fine, until I added a php.ini file to my root folder.

Problem: the first function get_service() will work as before, but the second one doesn't work. I can tell this function is called by seeing "before ajax", but this ajax call will not be successful as I don't see "after ajax".

```
$(function(){
    get_service();
})

function get_service(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "price-list/price.php?tab_name=tab_name",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            //something on success
        }
    });
}

$("#auto-btn-service").change(function(){
    alert("before ajax");
    $.ajax({
        url: "price-list/price.php?tab="+service,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            alert("after ajax");
        }
    });
})
```

In my php.ini file, I have these lines only

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 100M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 100M

extension=uploadprogress.so ;
```

I tried to empty this php.ini file, it still didn't work. I tried to move php.ini to the same directory as my page, it didn't work. Only deleting it can solve the problem. Anyone has any idea? Or any idea how to configure upload file size without using php.ini?(note my hosting doesn't allow me to configure via .htaccess)

Comment: The problem with user `php.ini` files is that they do not add to the global configuration but rather, they reset it. This means any directive not specified in your `php.ini` file reverts to its default value. Try [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) instead

Comment: Also, you should be checking the HTTP response from the failed AJAX calls in your browser's developer console (try the *Net* / *Network* tab). That will give you some insight as to the cause of the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment (and providing your host is using PHP >= 5.3.0), use a [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/configuration.file.per-user.php) file in the directory containing your script

```
; .user.ini

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 100M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 100M

extension=uploadprogress.so
```

Comment: Forgot to mention I have also set suPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html in my .htaccess file to enable php.ini to be red globally. However, changing php.ini to .user.ini actually works!!! How amazing it is

Comment: I don't understand how this is causing the problem

Comment: @LionLiu As per my comment above, with all other settings reverting to default, you're probably missing some extensions (like mysql, PDO, etc) and your script is erroring

Comment: Hey, I finally get your the point in your comment. Thanks very much @Phil

Comment: No probs. This used to be a massive pain point for me. Pre 5.3, it was [even worse](http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2009/08/php-suexec-and-custom-php-ini-files/)